# Node.js application crashes with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am using node.js for an application, I'm also using mysql to allow users to connect on the app.

I was using the application on local, and it was working pretty well, no crash, nothing bad.

Today I tried to put the js server on my dedicate server and the client on my web server.

Now that it is uploaded, I try to launch the server, but it crashes after a few seconds with these tracebacks :

```
events.js:48

    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:73:13)
    at Socket.onend (stream.js:80:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:388:51)
```

The connection code is simple :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'hostname',
    user : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'database',
});
connection.connect();
```

I tried to add a column into my db just after the connection and it works fine, my database which is on a different server than the js server accepts the connection and adds the column.

I don't know why I don't have these errors while I'm working on local...

Comment: can you try this connection.connect(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

and see if you are getting any errors printed

Comment: I just got a "null" printed, and then the server crashed after a while.

Comment: what NPM Module are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql, MD5, and socket.io

Comment: Since the MySQL server seems to be explicitly closing the connection, it will probably log the reason for that somewhere. Check your MySQL server log files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the open connections on your MySQL server. I had a similar issue and the problem was I wasn't releasing connections. So it would crash when the number of open connections hit my 150 connection limit. To check number of open connections use:

```
select * from information_schema.processlist;
```